# Xpath validation wiremock matchesXPath expression

Tags: java, json, xpath, soap, wiremock

I am creating cases with Wiremocks and I am generating a response mock.

I have a XML request like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xw="http://example.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <xw:gen>
            <xw:input>
                <xw:element1>0100</xw:element1>
                <xw:element2>741</xw:element2>
                <xw:element3>JAVA</xw:element3>
                <xw:element4>123</xw:element4>
            </xw:input>
            <xw:global>
                <xw:obj1>
                    <xw:attr1>john</xw:attr1>
                    <xw:attr2>doe</xw:attr2>
                </xw:obj1>
            </xw:global>
        </xw:gen>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I only have to validate that **xw:input/xw:element1 = 0100**, **xw:input/xw:element2 = 741** and I need that the **xw:global** node has anything. The only condition for **xw:global is not empty**. (This node can be `<xw:global></xw:global>`).

This is my mock in json:

```
{
    "request" : {
        "url" : "/myweb/myrequest.asmx",
        "headers": {
            "SOAPAction": {
                "equalTo": "\"http://example.com/gen\""
            }
        },
        "bodyPatterns" : [ {
            "matchesXPath": "//xw:input[xw:element1=\"0100\" and xw:element2=\"741\" ]",
            "xPathNamespaces" : {
                "xw" : "http://example.com"
            }
        }]
    },
    "response" : {
        "status" : 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        "body" : "<Abody>"
    }
}
```

The question is: how I can validate that the node **xw:global** is not empty or is not null?

I tried with this matchesXPath but I didn't have lucky:

`"matchesXPath": "//xw:input[xw:element1=\"0100\" and xw:element2=\"741\" ] and count(//xw:global) > 0"`.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you specify the namespaces in the stub definition? If not, then you can't use them in the XPath expression.

Comment: Yes. I specified the namespaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with wiremock, but you may want to try the following XPath :

```
"//xw:gen[xw:input[xw:element1=\"0100\" and xw:element2=\"741\"]][xw:global/*]"
```

The XPath above check if there is any `xw:gen` that :

- `[xw:input[xw:element1=\"0100\" and xw:element2=\"741\"]]` : have child element `xw:input` with the criteria you mentioned
- `[xw:global/*]` : and have child element `xw:global` containing, at least, one other element of any name

Comment: Hi @har07. In my case the node xw:global can be <xw:global/> and I used this validation: `[count(xw:globalObj)>0]`. But your response has been very useful. Thank you!!